# Why doesn't my jquery greyscale effect work on tumblr?

Tags: jquery, tumblr, grayscale

What I want to do is have all the images on my tumblr page be greyscale, and then slowly fade back to color on mouseover. I have a nice jquery script that I got [here](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/html5-grayscale-image-hover) that I've been able to get working on a HTML file saved to my hard drive with no problems. Since the script works, I assumed it's a problem with tumblr, so I added a little code snippet found on latenite.tumblr.com. Again, it works on a regular web page saved to my hard drive, but not on my tumblr page.

My tumblr:
http://marykellyreed.tumblr.com

I'm also open to using CSS to achieve this effect, but in my search, I was only able to find CSS solutions that toggled quickly between greyscale and color - no slow smooth transitions.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

From the error message, it looks like this is a cross domain / origin issue (Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data).

The javascript files would need to be hosted on the same site as its being requested, so maybe worth uploading the files to Tumblr: http://www.tumblr.com/themes/upload_static_file